# Where to declare a color variable in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Hello i 've made some new color variables in my ionic 5 project. I've put them in theme/variables.scss but the colors are not shown as do tetriary, secondary, primary and so on. Do i have to declare them somewhere else than variables.scss? The new color variables i ve made are brown, purple, orange

variables.scss file.

```
 :root {
  --ion-toolbar-background: #f5f5f53d!important;
  /** primary **/
  --ion-color-primary: #333;
  --ion-color-primary-rgb: 28,28,28;
  --ion-color-primary-contrast: #f5f5f5;
  --ion-color-primary-contrast-rgb: 245,245,245;
  --ion-color-primary-shade: #191919;
  --ion-color-primary-tint: #1C1C1C;

  /** secondary **/
  --ion-color-secondary: #f5f5f5;
  --ion-color-secondary-rgb: 245,245,245;
  --ion-color-secondary-contrast: #333;
  --ion-color-secondary-contrast-rgb: 31,31,31;
  --ion-color-secondary-shade: #cccc;
  --ion-color-secondary-tint: #999;
  
  /** gold **/
  --ion-color-gold: #dfb24f;
  --ion-color-gold-rgb: 223,178,79;
  --ion-color-gold-contrast: #000000;
  --ion-color-gold-contrast-rgb: 0,0,0;
  --ion-color-gold-shade: #d4af37;
  --ion-color-gold-tint: #d8b74b;

   /** gold-white **/
   --ion-color-gold-white: #d4af37;
   --ion-color-gold-white-rgb: 212,175,55;
   --ion-color-gold-white-contrast: #ffffff;
   --ion-color-gold-white-contrast-rgb: 0,0,0;
   --ion-color-gold-white-shade: #bb9a30;
   --ion-color-gold-white-tint: #d8b74b;
 
  /** tertiary **/
  --ion-color-tertiary: #4284f3;
  --ion-color-tertiary-rgb: 66, 132, 243;
  --ion-color-tertiary-contrast: #000000;
  --ion-color-tertiary-contrast-rgb: 0,0,0;
  --ion-color-tertiary-shade: #009ae0;
  --ion-color-tertiary-tint: #1ab7ff;

   /** orange **/
   --ion-color-orange: #FF8C00;
   --ion-color-orange-rgb: 255, 145, 0;
   --ion-color-orange-contrast: #000000;
   --ion-color-orange-contrast-rgb: 0,0,0;
   --ion-color-orange-shade: #FFA500    ;
   --ion-color-orange-tint:#FF4500  ;

/** purple **/
--ion-color-purple: #800080;
--ion-color-purple-rgb: 128,0,128;
--ion-color-purple-contrast: #D8BFD8;
--ion-color-purple-contrast-rgb: 0,0,0;
--ion-color-purple-shade: #800080;
--ion-color-purple-shade-rgb: 215,216,218;
--ion-color-purple-tint: #800080;
--ion-color-purple-tint-rgb: 245,246,249;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to declare the class in the variable.scss like this.

```
    .ion-color-brown {
  --ion-color-base: var(--ion-color-brown);
  --ion-color-base-rgb: var(--ion-color-brown-rgb);
  --ion-color-contrast: var(--ion-color-brown-contrast);
  --ion-color-contrast-rgb: var(--ion-color-brown-contrast-rgb);
  --ion-color-shade: var(--ion-color-brown-shade);
  --ion-color-tint: var(--ion-color-brown-tint);
}
```